# Fetching data when specific tabs is selected - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, tabs

Let's say I have two tabs "Car" and a "Bus" and also a boolean "isItCar" which defaults to true.

```
const [isItCar, setIsItCar] = useState(true)
```

We do need that boolean as it's part of our API (api/isItCar when true returns cars, when false returns buses)

They have the same data, apart from the category, and they also share a layout.

Now, I wonder, what is the best way to deal with this? Should I make two API calls, or pass the boolean as api/{isItCar}? Is it even possible to do so?
I would like to avoid duplicating code.

What should my tabs onselected method look like?

For example:

```
 <Tabs defaultActiveKey="cars" onSelect={ToggleCars}>
        <Tab eventKey="cars" title="Cars">
            <CardGroup>
                <CarList />
            </CardGroup>
        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey="buses" title="Buses" >
            <CardGroup>
                   <CarList />
            </CardGroup>
        </Tab>
    </Tabs>
```

And the ToggleCars method looks like this:

```
   const ToggleCars = (isItCar) => {
    setIsItCar(!isItCar);
    console.log("car bool: ", isItCar);
}
```

Now, whenever I click on the 'Bus' tabs the console actually outputs correct bool but when I try to call data if isItCar equals to false nothing happens.

Any advice on what should I do or in which direction should I go?

Answer (score 1):

If the tabs were toggle key then boolean would be the best option but passing two API calls is better. It's because a tab tag isn't chosen by boolean logic.

Let's say a user clicked Bus tag. Then the state will be changed from `true` to `false` and vice versa.

But when a user clicked Car tag from Car tag. Then the state `isItCar` will be changed from true to false though the Car tag is chosen still and vice versa.

So the state should be used as `string`. When a user clicks either tag, the state should set to the tag's name like 'cars' or 'buses'. The code would be like below,

```
const [isItCar, setIsItCar] = useState('cars')

   const ToggleCars = (isItCar) => {
    //The eventKey value from each tag should pass the state
    setIsItCar(event.value.eventKey);
    console.log("car bool: ", isItCar);
}
```